# How to check if element exists in map() React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have working code

```
const products = this.state.products.map((product, i) => 
        product.fields.company.fields.slug === this.props.match.params.slug ?
        <Suspense key={i} fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <ProductListItem id={i} key={i} product={product} />
        </Suspense>
        : null)

        return(
            <div className="partner-details" style={partnerD}>
                <div className="container-xl">
                    <Button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.props.history.goBack}>
                        <i className="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>&nbsp; Get back
                    </Button>
                    <ul>
                        <div className="product-item">
                            {products}
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>             
        )
```

But the problem is if `product.fields.company.fields.slug` (company.fields.slug) does not exist my code crashes.
How can I add extra ternary operator to check if it  `product.fields.company` exist before execute this `product.fields.company.fields.slug === this.props.match.params.slug`

Thanks!

Comment: You could use `(product.fields && product.fields.company && product.fields.company.fields && product.fields.company.fields.slug) === this.props.match.params.slug ...` but then you'll have another problem because you're not doing anything with the result of the ternary operation.

Comment: Sometimes it's best not to use a ternary expression -- code becomes hard to read. I suggest just using an if statement or 2 to make sure of this

Comment: You can use the filter function `this.state.products.filter(...).map(...)` to remove all elems without a specific field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your environment has support for [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) you can do this

```
product?.fields?.company?.fields?.slug === this.props.match.params.slug ?  .. : ..
```

otherwise you need to check that each field is truthy

```
product && product.fields && product.fields.company && product.fields.company.fields && product.fields.company.fields.slug === this.props.match.params.slug ? .. : ..
```

Answer (score 2):

In line 2 you can do:
`(product && product.fields && product.fields.company && product.fields.company.fields && product.fields.company.fields.slug && this.props && this.props.match && this.props.match.params && this.props.match.params.slug && product.fields.company.fields.slug === this.props.match.params.slug) ?`

or use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: You've got two `product.fields.company` in there.

Comment: Thank you, fixed it now and added checks for this, still I think if at all possible optional chaining is much more readable and preferred way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Use [optional-chaining](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) ( Babel plugin )

```
product.fields?.company?.fields?.slug
```

Or make use of the [`||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) :

```
(((product.fields || {}).company || {}).fields || {}).slug
```

And consider wrapping your compoennt in an [error boundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) so your app won't crash when there's this kind of errors.